# Hide dates in UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime

I want to hide the past as well as future dates from my UIDatePicker. Only want to show today's date. Is it possible?
Right now all the dates are coming, but only today's date is selecting. Time is also there. So in short I want to select today's date time by showing today's date only.

Comment: Why show a date picker then?

Comment: then there is no need for datepicker

Comment: for that no need datepicker....use custom pickerview

Comment: Use only timepicker don't add date feature in picker itself.

Answer (score 1):

Than no need to add DatePicker.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString        *dateString;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```